# Realizar serie de Fibonacci mediante un bucle ‘dowhile()’

Tags: javascript

hola me pueden ayudar donde tengo el error, tengo que hacer un función  fibonacci mediante un bucle ‘dowhile

```
function fibonacci(numero)
var i =2;
    {
        var numeros=[0,1];
        do ( i < numero; i++) {
            numeros[i] = numeros[i - 2] + numeros[i - 1];
        }
        return numeros;
    }

    while(document.write(fibonacci(6)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores en tu código:

- La variable `var i=2` la has declarado fuera de la función. Fíjate que la has dejado fuera de las llaves de la función.
- En un bucle `do-while` la condición va en el `while`, no el `do`.
- La condición del `while` la has sacado fuera de la función y tendría que estar dentro, junto a las llaves del bucle. Además, estas intentando escribir el resultado desde ahí, pero la parte del `while` es para escribir la condición por lo que no vas a poder escribr desde ella.
- Desde fuera de la función puedes escribir el resultado de la función, pero sin tener que llamar a la parte `while` del bucle.

Tu código corregido:

```js
function fibonacci(numero)
{
    var i=2;
    var numeros=[0,1];
    do{
        numeros[i] = numeros[i - 2] + numeros[i - 1];
        i++;
    }while(i < numero)
    return numeros;
}

document.write(fibonacci(6));
```

Comment: gracias francisco ya lo he visto ahora  me lió un poco pero poco a poco ya aprenderé